# In a music scale why C ? why not D♭♭ or B♯?

Tags: theory, notation, scales, composition, sheet-music

Theoretical speaking how can I tell the correct scale name between these three scales?

`B♯` ==> `C` <== `D♭♭` ?

Comment: Db isn't equivalent to C, but Dbb would be. I've closed this as a duplicate that goes into the distinction of when notes are used and why. If this isn't what you were asking, please make it a little clearer what exactly you want to know.